# UIImage Context editing causes SIGABRT / EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiimage, editing

I've got a pretty strange behaviour on my code. I want to edit some graphical stuff within an UIGraphicsImageContext. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm detaching the image proccessing function to a new thread which looks like this:

```
-(void)process:(SEL)function withObject:(id)sender {
UIActivityIndicatorView  *av = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];
av.frame = CGRectMake(round((self.view.frame.size.width - 50) / 2), 
                      round((self.view.frame.size.height - 50) / 2), 50, 50);
av.tag  = kActivityTag;
[self.view addSubview:av];
[av startAnimating];
[self enableControls:NO];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:function toTarget:self withObject:sender];
```

Before the process function is called by one of this functions like that:

```
-(void)imageColorTintChanged:(id)sender {
[self process:@selector(tint:) withObject:sender];}

-(void)tint:(id)sender {
@synchronized(image) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    float f       = ((UISlider *)sender).value;
    NSInteger tag = ((UISlider *)sender).tag;
    if (tag == 0) {
        redTint = f;
    } else if (tag == 1) {
        greenTint = f;
    } else if (tag == 2) {
        blueTint = f;
    }
    previewImage = [ImageUtil colorizeImage:image color:[UIColor colorWithRed:redTint green:greenTint blue:blueTint alpha:1.0]];
    [imageView setImage:previewImage];
    [self processDidFinish];
    [pool release];
}}
```

Finally my graphic editing starts here on the new thread:

```
+ (UIImage *)colorizeImage:(UIImage *)baseImage color:(UIColor *)theColor {
if (baseImage) {
    @synchronized (baseImage) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseImage.size);  // CRASH!!

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGRect area = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, baseImage.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);    

        [theColor set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, area);

        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
}
return baseImage;
```

Most of the time it crashes in this line:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseImage.size);

What could it possibly be? A threading thing?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Well, i made an activity monitor test on Instruments and for some reason it says no memory leak, but the real Memory usage goes up to 53 MB after some image processing and then it crashes. Is it possible that it's just some "I use too much memory" Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html), regarding `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`:

> You should call this function from the main thread of your application only.

You'll need to create a `CGBitmapContext` here instead.